# Domain using external models - Odoo 9

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

Im trying to do a filter between models on my xml view file. but I can't use values from a external model.

Actually I'm tryng to filter the options for a field(M2O) based on a previous selection.

> Myview.xml trys to render this
>
> Attributes:[Select an attribute from the list]
>
> Version   :[Select version here (from the available versions for the previously selected attribute)]

There is my models

```
alternative_model
    code                    =   fields.Char('code', required=True, size=6)
    description             =   fields.Char('description', required=True)
    attribute_type_id       =   fields.Many2one('attribute', required=True)
    attribute_version_id    =   fields.Many2one('version', required=True)

alternative_model
    code            =   fields.Char('code', required=True, size=2)
    description     =   fields.Char('description', required=True)
    alternative_ids =   fields.One2many('alternative','attribute_version_id')

alternative_model
    code            =   fields.Char('code',required=True,size=6)
    attribute_id    =   fields.Many2one('attribute',required=True)
    description     =   fields.Char('description',required=True)
    tag_ids         =   fields.One2many('tag','attribute_version_id')
```

I'm using the following domain:
`<field string="version" name="attribute_version_id" domain="[([attribute_type_id.code], '=',[attribute_version_id.attribute_id.code])]"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i this case you need to use onchange method to update the domain
of your many2one field:

```
  @api.onchange('attribute_type_id')
  def onchage_attribute(self):
    if self.attribute_type_id:# check if the user has selected an attribute
        # cancel the selected version 
        #but you can check if it much the domain before seting to False
        self.attribute_version_id = False 
        # return the new domain
        return {'domain':{'attribute_version_id':[('attribute_id', '=', self.attribute_type_id.id)]}
    else: # remove the domain 
        return {'domain':{'attribute_version_id':[]}
```

Comment: Works great. I still have to practice more with functions and api decorators

Comment: yes onchange now is more powerfull then ever with the new api

Answer (score 0):

Your xml seems to be wrong.

1./ You are trying the domain using same field, which you are trying to display on the screen, which is wrong. 
2./ This domain will not work, as it will not allow to access the other models attribute on the right side of the operator, in your case it is **'='**.

Try using the **'name_search'** method for **'attribute_version_id'**, you can pass the required value using **context** and based on that, you can filter out the records for **'attribute_version_id'**.

Try taking "related" field.